# q-separator with left closing and right opening

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

From the example here:
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/separator#usage
You can see that using `<q-separator inset="item" />` we can get separator with left opening and right closing (it's the original separator in the attached image)
Is there away to do the opposite (left closing and right opening) as highlighted in the red line below?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I see there is no design/option to make it in the left.

Looking at the code though, it just uses `margin-left` and `margin-right`:

[image]

So if you want it from the left you can swap the values to:

```css
.q-separator--horizontal-item-inset {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 72px;
}
```

[See codepen example](https://codepen.io/Roland1993/pen/LYjXEvo)